# Put Django ORM iterations to one request

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I have three models:

```
class Box(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)


class Toy(models.Model):
    box = models.ForeignKey(Box, related_name='toys')


class ToyAttributes(models.Model):
    toy = models.ForeignKey(Toy)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, related_name='colors')
```

And list:

```
pairs = [[10, 3], [4, 5], [1, 2]]
```

Where every value is a pair or box and color id's.
I need to filter this data and return boxes objects with toys of needed color.

Now I do this:

```
for n in list:
    box = Box.objects.filter(id=n[0], toys__colors=n[1])
    if box.exist():
        ...
```

But it takes a lot of time for long lists, as I understand because of multiple SQL requests. Can I make it faster? Is it possible to get only needed boxes with one request and how can I make it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at django [Q function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and construct your query in a loop adding values to Q like so

```
query = Q()
for box_id, toy_color in [[10, 3], [4, 5], [1, 2]]:
   query |= Q(Q(id=box_id) & Q(toys__colors=toy_color))
Box.objects.filter(query)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
from django.db.models import Q

pairs = [[10, 3], [4, 5], [1, 2]]

conditions = [Q(id=box) & Q(toys__colors=color) for box, color in pairs]

query = Q()
for c in conditions:
    query |= c

Box.objects.filter(query)
```